# Selenium Fluentwait implementation for Webdriver.io

Tags: selenium, webdriver, webdriver-io

Is there any **FluentWait** implementation available for WebdriverIO?

Looking for something similar to the Selenium Java `FluentWait` implementation, for example one below:

```
Wait wait = new FluentWait(WebDriver reference)
  .withTimeout(timeout, SECONDS)
  .pollingEvery(timeout, SECONDS)
  .ignoring(Exception.class);

WebElement foo=wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
  public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
    return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
  }
});
```

I tried searching on various docs, but couldn't find an equivalent. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [waitUntil](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/waitUntil.html) api for that

```
    it('should wait until element is existing for 5000ms with 250ms polling', () => {
      browser.waitUntil(() => {
         return $('#someText').isExisting();  // condition
       }, 5000, 'expected element to be exist after 5s', 250);
    });
```

it doesn't have ignore exception but maybe you can add try catch in condition function. But it will provide all the other functionalities.